# Apply webkit scrollbar style to specified element

Tags: css, webkit, pseudo-element

I am new to pseudo-elements that are prefixed with a double colon. I came across a blog article discussing styling of scrollbars using some webkit only css. Can the pseudo-element CSS be applied to individual elements?

```
/* This works by applying style to all scroll bars in window */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* This does not apply the scrollbar to anything */
div ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
```

In this fiddle, I would like to make the div's scrollbar customized, but the main window's scrollbar stay at the default.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/4xMUB/1/

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Your idea was correct. However, the notation `div ::-webkit-scrollbar` with a space after `div` is actually the same as `div *::-webkit-scrollbar`; this selector means "scrollbar of any element inside `<div>`". Use `div::-webkit-scrollbar`.

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/4xMUB/2/

Comment: Be careful to not put white space between div and ::-webkit.. That took me a time to know why this does not work, the problem was the white space.

Answer (score 43):

I want to use a class selector for using a custom scrollbar.

Somehow `.foo::-webkit` doesn't work, but I figured out that `div.foo::-webkit` does work! Those ##$$*## pseudo-things....

See http://jsfiddle.net/QcqBM/16/

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip. Probably another thing that would have wasted two hours of my time another day.

Comment: Not true anymore

Comment: This works! Tried multiple ways to get webkit rule work inside the container class but adding element tag in front somehow applies it correctly.

Comment: I needed a space for this to work: `div.foo ::-webkit-scrollbar`

Answer (score 20):

You can also apply these rules by id of the element. Let's say scroll bar of a div has to be styled which has an id "myDivId". Then you can do following. This way you can use different styles for scroll bars of different elements.

```
#myDivId::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

#myDivId::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#myDivId::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QcqBM/516/

Comment: Could you apply it on class name as well ?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a scss file and apply the style to a class there

style.scss

```
.myscrollbar {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: linear-gradient(13deg, #f9d4ff 14%, #c7ceff 64%);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(13deg, #c7ceff 14%, #f9d4ff 64%);
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 7px 10px 12px #f0f0f0;
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<div class="myscrollbar">
put your contents here
</div>
```

I used the scrollbar generator here: https://w3generator.com/scrollbar