# Applying multiple CSS styles to webkit scrollbars

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbars

I know that we can style the webkit scrollbar like so:
http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

However, this applies the scrollbar style to the main browser window and all elements within it (ie: Scrollable DIV's, select boxes, etc...)

Is there a way to apply different scrollbar styles to different elements? For example, let's say I want the scrollbar of a DIV to be different than the scrollbar of the main window. Can I do anything like:

```
DIV::-webkit-scrollbar {
   background:#ff0000;
}
```

(This doesn't work but perhaps you'll understand what I'm looking to do)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple custom scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325322/multiple-custom-scrollbars)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7743840/2039750