# How to make scrollbar always visible in angular material?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, scrollbar

So currently, I'm using angular material and its default scroll (But I think it is perfect scrollbar) to use as a scroll design to my scroll bar. But the scroll is only showing if the users try to scroll the page/div. I tried to read the scrolling api of the Angular Material but there's no attribute that I can use in here. And I do already put the `overflow-y: scroll` on the css of course. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I found a work around, I need to include `pseudo` class to my CSS

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

And if you need it to a specific element or container

```
.selectionTable::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}

.selectionTable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

Reference:

[Making the main scrollbar always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31278615/2637261)

[Apply webkit scrollbar style to specified element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7743982/2637261)

Comment: @VikasJadhav Good point. But who uses Angular 7 then target an old browser?

Comment: if you think no one is using old browsers with angular 7 then go with your approach..because many big organisations still using old ones

Comment: This is a non-standard feature and it won't work on some browsers, tablets and phones (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar). There is no a stable CSS solution for this issue. The only cross-platform way to do it is to deal with it with JS.