# Custom scrollbar CSS is not working for div

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am developing extension for Chrome and I made custom scrollbar. But I want to apply a different design inside the element named "#details". But it doesn't work. It only works for the whole page. Can you help me?

**This is working...**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
border-radius: 1ex;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
background: var(--theme-color);
border-radius: 1ex;
}
```

**But this is not working, Why?**

```
#details::-webkit-scrollbar{
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
}

#details::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
border-radius: 1ex;
}

#details::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
background: var(--theme-color);
border-radius: 1ex;
border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: can you please attach your whole code here

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743840/apply-webkit-scrollbar-style-to-specified-element these solutions once

Comment: Stackoverflow sent error, So you can look github.

https://github.com/kortopal/11a/blob/main/11A%20Eklenti/css/main.css

If you look at the Github code you won't see that I have added the scrollbar code for #details. Because it doesn't work so I didn't upload it.

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't work because it has a chrome extension?

Comment: Oh my god! :D I wrote wrong id. I solved problem.